# Removing inline styles from JSON response using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm using JSON to receive content from a Wordpress website and display it on my mobile app. The JSON response I'm receiving has some inline styles within it that I don't need. I do however like to keep the actual html structure. Is this something that I can do with Javascript/jQuery?

For example, I like this:

```
<span style="color: red;">some text</span>
<p style="text-align: right;">Other stuff</p>
```

Turn to this:

```
<span>some text</span>
<p>other stuff</p>
```

Comment: Not sure I get it, your JSON looks a lot like HTML to me? And then you could just remove the style attribute?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a jQuery object from your HTML string and then use `.removeAttr()` as others have said:

```
var $result = $(yourHTMLString);

$result.find('[style]').removeAttr('style');
```

Comment: Don't you mean `.removeAttr('style');`?

Comment: Awesome, learning something new everyday. I can use it as $result[0] after stripping all the inline styles. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`removeAttr()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeattr/) method to remove attributes, try this:

```
$("span").removeAttr('style');
```

---

**Update**

> My JSON response is just text, it's not a DOM element that I can use removeAttr on

In that case you can convert the response text to a jQuery object and run the `removeAttr()` on that:

```
var $html = $(jsonResponseData);
$html.find('span').removeAttr('style');
```

Comment: My JSON response is just text, it's not a DOM element that I can use removeAttr on.